# Memory Limit - JBoss AS 7

Tags: performance, jboss, scaling

We got a plan to port an existing Legacy Enterprise RMI application (which consumes more than 3-4 GB memory) to JBoss AS 7. This is so that the application can be better managed / scaled (server-cluster).

Does anyone have any idea if JBoss AS 7 is suitable for this activity or wont create memory related issues?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this shouldn't be a problem with a proper GC-strategy.